# Typescript project yields: Error: Cannot find module 'sharp'

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, sharp

This seems to be a fairly common issue, but having already tried all the solutions in other threads - have no choice but to make a new question so I can enclose my files and exact error.

As per the docs, I have also installed sharp like this, doesnt fix:

```
npm install
rm -rf node_modules/sharp
SHARP_IGNORE_GLOBAL_LIBVIPS=1 npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux --libc=glibc sharp
```

I have a typescript project for an AWS Lambda function that I'm testing using `sam local invoke`, and am getting the following error:

```
{"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'sharp'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'sharp'","Require stack:","- /var/task/index.js","- /var/runtime/index.mjs","    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1061:17)","    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1093:21)","    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1256:23)","    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1262:1"]}
```

I have tried rebuilding, rm -r node_modules, reinstalling, with both Yarn and NPM. As per the docs, I include `--external:sharp` in my esbuild command.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.400.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.18",
    "sharp": "^0.32.6",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.104",
    "@types/sharp": "^0.31.1",
    "esbuild": "^0.15.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rm -rf dist",
    "build": "esbuild ./src/index.ts --bundle --minify --sourcemap --platform=node --target=es2020 --outfile=dist/index.js",
    "postbuild": "cd dist && zip -r index.zip index.js*",
    "upload": "aws lambda update-function-code --function-name sendBackWebP-originResponse --zip-file fileb://dist/index.zip --region us-east-1",
    "test-lambda": "esbuild ./src/index.ts --bundle --minify --sourcemap --platform=node --target=es2020 --external:sharp --outfile=dist/index.js && sam local invoke -e ./src/200-event.json OriginResponseFunction"
  }
}
```

import:

```
import Sharp from "sharp";
```

I can get this working fine on a js project, but always get this error when attempting on typescript. Anyone have an idea how to fix this? Thanks